# .htaccess setup to allow react router to work without preventing API calls to server

Tags: reactjs, apache, .htaccess

When I deployed my react app to a static server it crashed on refreshing the web browser. To fix this I added the following code to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

This resolved the rendering issue as it no longer sent a get request for the URL but used React router instead. However, this is now causing an issue where any API calls are now failing to go through to my server, but are instead being served the index.html file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, im a bit late but you can add a rewrite condition to check if the request uri has api on it.
Let´s assume you have your api on the folder api/ at the root directory, so your folder structure looks like this:

```
/.htaccess
/index.html ----> your react entry point
/api/ ----> here is your api files
/assets/
```

Your htaccess right now tells every request to go to the index.html file
but you can add the code bellow at the start of the .htaccess to detect a api call:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
RewriteRule ^ api/index.php [L]
```

this should work, i tested it using xampp 8.

Comment: Of course that is assuming you are using a php api, you can adjust the entry point changing the RewriteRule to match the server youre using (in case of Node.js or other)